# iOS moving views within a container confuses the touch region

Tags: ios, view, containers

I have placed 2 views (table views) within a view container that are partially overlapped, on purpose.  View B overlaps about 50% of View A.

When I programatically move View B so they no longer overlap, the previously overlapped region within View A does not respond to touch events, that is, ~50% does not. Only the region that wasn't orginally overlapped does.  In addition, within View B, the portion that is now occupying new space within the superview, does not respond to touch events, only the portion of the view that happens to occupy the old region.

The code is simple that I'm using to move the view:

```
UIView* viewB = [self.childViewControllers.lastObject view];

CGRect rect = viewB.frame;
rect.origin.x += 200;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    viewB.frame = rect;
}];
```

Visually, the view moves but the touch region doesn't.

I used the new storyboard "Container View" mechanism within iOS 6 to initially place the views.

I have no idea why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The anamation block I'm using is independent of the issue.  In fact, I don't need an animation block at all and the issue is still there.  The suggested option is useful if I want user interaction *during* the animation.  It's not like touch events don't work, they don't work on a portion of the view - the portin where it was originally overlapping.  It's as if my app still believes my view hasn't moved.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, when xCode adds the "Container View" within my storyboard, it embeds my view within a parent view.  So I need to do the following:

```
UIView* viewB = [[self.childViewControllers.lastObject view] superview];

CGRect rect = viewB.frame;
rect.origin.x += 200;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    viewB.frame = rect;
}];
```

Because the container embeds my view within it's own view, I need to get the superview and work with that.

If I were to do all of this programatically, that is, add the container and view myself using the container API, my original code would work.

Comment: Wow this had been bugging me for an hour. Thanks for posting the answer to your own question!